# Octave: saving figure with greek letters and subscripts

Tags: save, special-characters, octave, figure

I'm currently trying to save a stress vs. strain curve using Octave. On this plot, I want to include text showing the equation for calculating engineering stress and engineering strain. Both of these require greek letters (\sigma and \epsilon respectively) as well as subscripts for the formulae.

Currently, using print with -deps, -dpng, or any other device, it creates a file, however the greek letters appear as the words "sigma" and "epsilon", and wherever I have a subscript, such as 0, it just appears as "_0". This looks very unprofessional.

Since I'm generating some 25 graphs, I don't want to have to go through and do a screenshot for each one. Does octave support saving the generated figure as displayed? I intend to use the generated files in a LaTeX document later (preferably as png so I can email them separately too).

I've also tried changing the "graphics_toolkit" option between fltk and gnuplot however it doesn't seem to help.

Attached to this post is a screenshot of the desired results and the actual results.

I am currently "not allowed" to post images, so I'll link them:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZQE9.png (screenshot, desired result) and https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFHjc.png (directly saved, actual result)

Does anyone know a good way to print a figure from Octave which includes greek characters and subscripts in the titles?

Comment: See here http://wiki.octave.org/Printing_with_FLTK

Answer (score 2):

Since you plan to use your graph in a Latex document, generating the graphs with [-depslatex](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Printing-and-Saving-Plots.html) and converting them to pdf is a good idea . (Results look slightly better than direct -dpdflatex).
With -depslatex, you can include Latex code in your figures that will be written to a separate tex file.
Note that you need to use double backslashes `\\` to export a single backslash.

```
graphics_toolkit("gnuplot");
...
legend("$\\varepsilon$");
print(sprintf("graph%s_%d.eps", name, type), '-depslatex', '-S200,270', '-F:9');
system(sprintf("epstopdf graph%s_%d.eps", name, type));
```

On the Latex side, you then `\input` the tex file generated by Octave. On the plus side, since you need 25 graphs, you can automatize this process on both sides Octave and Latex.

```
\newcommand{\mygraph}[1]{%
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\resizebox{0.495\linewidth}{!}{\relscale{1.0}\small%
\input{./figures/#1.tex} 
}%
}
\mygraph{graph1_1}
```

Here, a Latex command `\mygraph` is defined to scale and include a figure located in a subfolder.

(I am using Octave 4.0.0 with gnuplot 4.4 on Ubuntu 12)